# Form validation using PHP and placing the error messages?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I made a registration form which when submitted checks to see if the user filled in all the fields, the username isn't taken, or the email isn't already in use. All of these validations work fine. But when the form is submitted, and let's say the user has submitted something invalid, the error message(s) of course appear one at a time on a different page. I want to make these messages appear all at once and on the same page as the form, so it is more user friendly. I tried to make the error message a variable, and then echo that variable in a table data cell, but the variable is "undefined". I tried to make the variable global, but I am having trouble doing this. Could anyone offer me some insight? Thank you...Here is an example of my code and what i want to do.

The PHP script...

```
    if($numrowsusername != 0)
    {

        $username_errormsg ='This user name is taken';
    }
```

The index page with the form where I want the message to show up...

```
    <td align ='left'><input type ='text' name = 'usernamereg' placeholder = 'Username' class = 'username2' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $username_errormsg; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a scope issue. Try declaring the `$username_errormsg` before the `if` as `$username_errormsg='';` Also, since you want all the error messages to appear at the same place, it would be better to store them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning error to the variable `$username_errormsg` ONLY if the error happens, your variable is undefinied as long as that error do not exist. So when you will get the error, your `echo $username_errormsg` is fine, but until then the notice will stay. What you can do is to check if the variable is defined by function `isset()`. It will look like this:

```
<?php if(isset($username_errormsg)) echo $username_errormsg; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and response. I will try this right away.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the error without checking if an error actually happened.  You can fix this using `!empty($username_errormsg)` function which will check that the variable is set and will also check that its not empty.

```
    <td align ='left'><input type ='text' name = 'usernamereg' placeholder = 'Username' class = 'username2' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if(!empty($username_errormsg)){
                    echo $username_errormsg;
                }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Also to echo the error on the same page you will have to either post the values on the **same page** using empty `action=""` field in the form or use **JavaScript** to do the validation for you before posting the data to the next page.  The JavaScript validation will just be for the user's convenience and you can internally check if the data is what you need on the next page using PHP

If JavaScript is in the cards you can look into [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to do the validation for you easily.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. So you are saying in order for the values to be posted on the same page without using JavaScript the form must be self submitting? I heard that JavaScript is not as safe to use for validation because it is client-side. Sorry for these noob questions I am a beginner but eager to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Yes it is not safe but you can validate by JavaScript on the same page and if it checks out good, post data to the next page where you can validate it again using php and if the check fails show an error or redirect the page to previous page using PHP `header()` JavaScript is just for convenience and making your page user friendly.  You should not depend on JavaScript alone.

Comment: If you want to add JS validation, you need to have PHP validation anyways, since anyone can disable JS.

Comment: @user3407857 ailvenge is correct.  But you can use JavaScript in your pages. Its not that you should completely avoid it.  Most websites now a days use it or i can say expect the user to enable it in his browser which includes this site too ).

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying JS is bad, just can't rely on it 100% :)

Comment: I did exactly what you said and now the validation works and the error messages appear under each field. But because I wrote the validation as a bunch of nested if statements, the error messages appear one at a time. Is there anyway to make all the error messages appear at once after the user submits the form? For example, let's say someone entered a username that was already taken AND an a password that was too short. Is there a way for both error messages to appear simultaneously?

Comment: Yes there is but validating form manually depends on the form fields and your business logic.  For convenience sake check out the 2 plugins I have pointed out in my answer they use JSON configuration and will make your validation pretty much easier. I'd recommend you use them and not do the validation manually using if statements.  If u see the plugin homepage they are pretty easy to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

make array of $error_message like this

```
if($numrowsusername != 0)
{

    $error_message['username'] ='This user name is taken';
}
```

`$error_message['username']="This user name is taken";
 $error_message['email']="email alreasy exists";`

then loop through it .

```
foreach($error_message as $key=>$value){
echo $error_message[$key'];
echo '<br />';
}
```